# C# Printing variables using an "EXEC" Command

Tags: c#, python, exec

In python to print a list of 11 Variables i would do so using "Exec". There is a list of 11 Items, this code prints them all.

```
for count in range(1,11):
    question = ("print " + "question" + str(count))
    exec question
```

How would I do something similar in C# ?
(Without the use of lists)

Here's what i have so far

```
string line;
for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
  {
line = ("Console.WriteLine(scene1_f"+i);
    // Execute "line"
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `exec` command in python?

Comment: Don't do that. Use an array instead of 200 different variables.

Comment: @blorgbeard and how would your suggestion help in achieving what OP asks: "How would I do something similar in C# ? (Without the use of lists)"

Comment: Ugh, I missed that "without lists". I still say it's a bad idea, OP should use lists unless he has a very good reason not to.

Comment: @Blorgbeard So in your opinion, in order to "to print a list of 11 Variables" in c# (i.e. the range [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] as in OP's example) a list would be needed?

Comment: @alex I don't think you understand the OP's question. That's not what his python code does. It prints the content of 10 variables named `question1`, `question2`, .. `question10`. It does this by executing dynamic python code.

Comment: @Blorgbeard ok, understood ... apparently I need to look up some python tutorials :D I will change my answer to better match OPs intentions

Comment: Executing dynamically generated code, like python's `exec` does, is just not the way to do things in C# (normally). It is possible, but it's not easy. 

If you just want to do it this way because you're used to doing it in python, I strongly suggest you reconsider and use an array instead. It's a whole lot easier.

If you actually have a very good reason that you can't use an array, look up "reflection in C#".

Comment: That said if you're using 'variables' that would generally mean they already exist at compile-time.  Why not just do a Console.WriteLine() for each one?  The restriction against using a list here smacks of either "do my homework" or an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be wise if you read a few things on the c# language while you are trying out stuff. At the same time, it would be wise if I looked up some Python tutorials before attempting to answer such questions.

Although c# supports dynamic types and expressions, it is mostly used to create "strongly typed" constructs. For the example you provided I believe there are no easy / simple direct translations.

Your "scene1_f1" through "scene1_f200" variables would likely be instances of some c# type like a `Scene` class, that has some properties and methods that operate on the object instance.

If you have multiple `Scene` object that you want to perform the same type of operation on (like printing them to the console as in your example), it is generally considered good practice to group them in some manner, such as adding them to a List or storing them in an Array.

To illustrate what I mean I have added a hypothetical example:

```
 public class Scene
 {
      public Scene(string name)
      {
          Name = name;
      }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      // ... more properties

      public void Draw()
      {
          // logic for drawing
      }

      // ... more methods.

      public override string ToString()
      {
          // here return what you would want to have as
          // a string representation of a Scene object.
          return "Scene " + Name;
      }
 }


 // in a different part of your code, create and add the Scene objects
 var scenesList = new List<Scene>();

 scenesList.Add(new Scene("Some scene name"));
 // add more

 // Now you can print them to the console like this:
 foreach (var scene in scenesList)
     Console.WriteLine(scene);
```